# Android: Button OnClickListener does not working

Tags: android, onclick, switch-statement, listener, case

I have created this activity that should allow me to open a new activity once a button has been pressed.

However the OnClickListener does not seem to be working.

Am I declaring the buttons wrong?

Can someone me out?

```
public class Menu extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    View loginbutton = findViewById(R.id.butlogin);
    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View recordbutton = findViewById(R.id.butrecordts);
    recordbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View viewbutton = findViewById(R.id.butviewts);
    viewbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    View projectsbutton = findViewById(R.id.butprojects);
    projectsbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void onClick(View v){

    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.butlogin:
    {
        //open login screen
        Intent i = new Intent(this, login.class);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
    case R.id.butrecordts:
    {
        break;
    }
    case R.id.butviewts:
    {
        break;
    }
    case R.id.butprojects:
    {
        break;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, The Problem is in Declaration of button, write below code instead of your code, it will solve your problem.

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button loginbutton, recordbutton, viewbutton, projectsbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        loginbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butlogin);
        loginbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        recordbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butrecordts);
        recordbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        viewbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butviewts);
        viewbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

        projectsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butprojects);
        projectsbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.butlogin:
            {
                //open login screen
                Intent i = new Intent(this, login.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.butrecordts:
            {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.butviewts:
            {
                break;
            }
            case R.id.butprojects:
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has resolved the problem. However, in doing so the app stops responding once a button is pressed.

Comment: It's asking if I have declared the activity in my android manifest. I have done so.

Comment: @HydarRoze OK, no problem.

Comment: This helped me! Thank you. I didn't set the onclicklistener for the view itself after setting the view.

Answer (score 4):

You forget to implement `onClickListener` in your Activity.

Implement it and then try :)

```
public class Menu extends Activity implements onClickListener
```

Comment: see my edited answer.Just replace this line with your code :)

Comment: @HydarRoze If my answer helpful to you,don't forget to accept and upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have just forgotten to implement the `onClickListener` in your activity:

> public class Menu extends Activity implements OnClickListener {  <----Check out this line
>             ............................
>              }

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line

```
 View loginbutton = findViewById(R.id.butlogin);
```

to

```
 Button  loginbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butlogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    View.OnClickListener myhandler1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // the 1st button
     }
    }
    View.OnClickListener myhandler2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
     //the 2nd button
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your buttons like this:

```
Button loginbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butlogin);
    loginbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button recordbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butrecordts);
    recordbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button viewbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butviewts);
    viewbutton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button projectsbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butprojects);
    projectsbutton.setOnClickListener(this);
```